# How to change a cell value when cells from two worksheet match and a separate specific value?

Tags: excel, excel-formula

Sheet1
[image: Sheet1]

Sheet2
[image: Sheet 2]

I am trying to do the following but I can't seem to work it out:

Sheet1 is my inventory, Sheet2 is supplier's inventory. We'll use SKU "AAA" as an example.

If Sheet2's SKU (A2) equals to Status "Out of Stock" (C2), match with Sheet1's SKU (E3) and change Quantity (D3) to "0"

In this case I will need SKU AAA, DDD and EEE's quantity to change to 0 in Sheet1.

What is the best formula for this if I have hundreds of SKU rows that needs to run daily? Is it possible to automate this using a macro?

Forgive me if the question is silly as I am very new to this, hopefully someone can shed some light and point me towards the right direction.

Comment: Hi @Joborobo, good question. You posted a couple of image links; best practice on SO is to post code samples, so they can be recreated easily by people trying to answer your question (or failing that, paste image directly into the question). Links get stale over time and then your question is meaningless. Also, consider changing the title of your question – it is unclear grammatically. I'll answer the question separately.

Answer (score 0):

You can use VB in Excel or use Formulas on in the excel sheets.
If I'm getting what you are asking correctly, you want to 'sync' your inventory[Quantity] with your supplier[Quantity]. If you are using the latest version of Excel you can use XLOOKUP and if the function is not available in your version of excel you can use VLOOKUP or use a combination of INDEX and MATCH.

In sheet1 on cell D2 you can try out these formulas

```
=XLOOKUP(E2,Sheet2!$A$2:$A$6,Sheet2!$B$2:$B$6,"Not Found",0,1)
=VLOOKUP(E2,Sheet2!$A$2:$C$6,2,FALSE)
=INDEX(Sheet2!$A$2:$B$6,MATCH(E2,Sheet2!$A$2:$A$6,0),2)
```

If your supplier quantity changes for an SKU it will automatically update your inventory quantity as well

**Revising based on your comment**

In VBA I would go through each row and get the SKU, then we use VLOOKUP to get the quantity in Sheet 2(Supplier), if the quantity is = 0 we update our inventory with 0 if not we do nothing thereby leaving the existing quantity in your inventory as is.

```
Sub DoThings()

Dim ws1 As Worksheet
Dim ws2 As Worksheet
Dim SupplierValue As Long
Dim LastRow As Integer
Dim InventorySKU As String
Dim SupplierQuantity As Integer


Set ws1 = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1")
Set ws2 = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet2")

LastRow = ws1.UsedRange.Rows.Count


For i = 2 To LastRow

InventorySKU = ws1.Cells(i, 5).Value

SupplierQuantity = CInt(Application.WorksheetFunction.VLookup(InventorySKU, ws2.Range("A2:C6"), 2, False))

If SupplierQuantity = 0 Then

ws1.Cells(i, 4).Value = 0

End If

Next i
 
End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks for your response! However I am not looking to sync the numbers, but for the quantity in sheet1 to show as 0 if the quantity in sheet2 is 0 or Out of Stock. If for example sheet1's quantity is 5 and sheet2's quantity is 8, I want the quantity in sheet1 to remain unchanged at 5.

Comment: I would do it in VBA (Macro), see my update answer, if i got what your want this time around. You can expand on that to suit your needs e.g If the inventory was updated to 0 but then you supplier added more inventory,this code won't cater for that hence you inventory won't be updated  :)

Answer (score 0):

The following formula sets your stock level to zero if the supplier's inventory shows Out of Stock.

```
=IF( VLOOKUP(B2,Sheet2!A1:C6,3,FALSE) = "Out of Stock", 0)
```

It does not, however, set your stock level to the appropriate amount if your supplier is not out of stock. To do that you would need a separate column showing your stock level, and you would need to supply that value after the 0 in the above formula:

```
=IF( VLOOKUP(B2,Sheet2!A1:C6,3,FALSE) = "Out of Stock", 0, <correct amt here>)
```

You might need to use VLOOKUP() in the "if false" clause to get the correct amount from that other column I mentioned.